# Почему значение переменной = NaN?

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <body>
    <div class="circle">
        <div class="unit"></div>
    </div>
<script src="script.js"></script>                                                                                                    /   </body>




let unit = document.querySelector(".unit");
let vh;
let vw;
setInterval((screenMeasure) => {
    vh = window.innerHeight / 100;
    vw = window.innerWidth / 100;
}, 1);
let unitHeight = 5 * vh;
```

Если в консоли набрать 5 * vh выдает нормальный результат, но если запросить unitHeight то результатом будет NaN.
Почему так?

Comment: _Почему так?_ - потому что присваивание `vh` выполняется в коллбеке setInterval

Comment: @Jean-Claude, причем тут область видимости?

Comment: да и вообще, setInterval() выполнится после строки unitHeight = 5 * vh

Comment: `undefined * 5 === NaN`

Comment: @ΝNL993 почему vh = undefined?

Comment: @Geharka потому что он был изменён через одну миллисекунду, а по стандарту он `undefined`. Либо делайте так: `let unitHeight; setTimeout(() => { unitHeight = 5 * vh })`, чтобы `vh` успел измениться и не был бы `undefined`, либо у вас будет `NaN`.